# Generating successive sums of an array in a functional way with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have an array of doubles in which I want to assign to another array the sum of elements successively from 0..n. Example: `r[0] = sum(a[0..n]), r[1] = sum(a[1..n]), r[m] = sum(a[m..n]) where m <= n` etc.

This is trivial to do with loops:

```
int n = a.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double sum = 0.;
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
         sum += a[j];
    r[i] = sum;
}
```

Is there a slick way to do this in Java 8 streams in a functional manner? With the library StreamEx I can get close with something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    r[i] = DoubleStreamEx.of(a).skip(i).sum();
```

I don't really care about performance this is more of an exercise to learn about streams.

Comment: `n <= a.length`?

Comment: *"This is trivial to do with loops"* Perhaps trivial, but you still managed to do it with bad performance (_O(n^2)_). The operation can be done with a single loop (_O(n)_). To do this using streams, you need a custom `Collector`, and it is very far from optimal performance. Optimal performance is easy to achieve using a `for` loop (easy, even though you managed to mess it up), so why go for sub-optimal stream code, when a single `for` loop will do it?

Comment: As I said, I don't care about performance

Comment: *"this is more of an exercise to learn about streams"* Then you should learn what streams are good for and what they are not good for. This is an example of "not good". Just because it can be achieved using streams (see [answer by shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45805917/5221149)), that doesn't mean that streams is the right tool for the job.

Comment: In case you're curious, I think @Andreas means something like this: `for (int sum = 0, i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) r[i] = sum += a[i];`

Comment: sure... yes streams are bad in this context, yes my example can be written with 1 loop.  This is part of the "exercise" of trying to understand how various imperative algorithms can be represented in a functional manner. . I picked Java as my example could as easily been Haskell.  I can still put in a screw with a hammer, doesn't mean I'll keep doing it once I find a screwdriver...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double[] r = IntStream.range(0, n)
        .mapToDouble(m -> Arrays.stream(a, m, n).sum())
        .toArray();
```